# Eevee - Renders Black in "Animation" but fine for single frame

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

I'm a fairly experienced Blender user, but this one is new to me. Running Windows and an RTX 3070.

I'm building a Lord of the Rings animation comprising of multiple scenes. All my cycles-based scenes work fine. I have one that I'm using Eevee for (contains volumetrics).

The viewport works fine:

[image]

If I render a single frame, it also works fine:

[image]

As soon as I go to animate the full sequence though, falls apart and crashes or just shows solid black:

[image]

I haven't got any objects with subsurf mods on them - I do have a fair few bools on the go, but given it's working in the Image Render, not sure they're the issue? No motion blur, just bloom enabled for Eevee.

Any ideas are most appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, small update in that it does actually seem to be rendering correctly to the file system, but the Render preview panel is the bugged part. So, it's functional, but any insight into why this might be happening is still most appreciated!

Comment: This may be just because there is a black render layer, and it doesn’t have time to show the rest of the layers.

Comment: when looking at your animations, I see that your animation frame and your render frame are on different frames... Potentially something could be moving in front of the camera, lights can be blocked or dimmed, motion blur, the camera could move...? If you tried rendering the still image on the frame you show of the animation you might get the same black screen...

Comment: Sometimes blender can just give up with lighting calculations, this happens with me sometimes. If you restart blender it recalculates and works again which may have been the case here as well...

Comment: @object "Potentially something could be moving in front of the camera, lights can be blocked or dimmed, motion blur, the camera could move...?" - this was just because I wasn't fast enough capturing the screenshot! The black is on every frame when animating, but fine for a single frame.

Comment: @object I'd also tried several restarts, but consistently happening unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, two things for the answer:

- The frames were in fact rendering to the file system without any issue, but the render preview looked broken (black) and the frame rendering rate was incredibly slow, especially for what is a simple scene.
- I found that my ground had two sets of Geometry Nodes on it, one to render the paper and one to render the rocks. I think the Geometry out from the Rock generator was then feeding into the Paper generator and the "Distribute Points on Faces" was having a field day. I've combined these two generators into a single Geometry Node set and the viewport performance has improved drastically. It also now animate without any issues at all, and much faster.

So, I think the actual issue was likely linked to Blender just losing it's mind on  the Geometry Nodes clashing.